# Dynamically added Views not visible

Tags: android, xamarin, view, visibility, layout-inflater

I am trying to add TextViews to a LinearLayout wrapped in a ScrollView during runtime, but the visibility of the TextViews will *eventually* not display on screen even though their visibility flags are all set to `Visible`.

```
myLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myScollLayout);

View myView = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_view, null);
TextView text1 = myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);
TextView text2 = myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text2);
TextView text3 = myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text3);
text1.Text = "text 1";
text2.Text = "text 2";
text3.Text = "text 3";
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
myLayout.AddView(myView, p);
myView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible
```

xml layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:id="@+id/myScrollLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I say *eventually* because at times the views in the above code display as expected, but eventually on subsequent executions of the code that inflates and adds the views, the views that are added to the inflated layout are not visible on screen. If I check the visbility of all child views, they all say `Visible`, but on screen they would seem to be displaying as `Invisible` since there is still space taken up inside the scroll layout, but is blank.

I've referenced a number of other articles that discuss using the following:

- View.Invalidate()
- View.RequestLayout()
- View.Post()
- RunOnUiThread()

but no combination of the above seem to get the views to appear. I have also implemented a function below to try to force all child views of `myScrollLayout` to be visible, but still has no impact as all views appear as if they are `Invisible`.

```
void SetVisibility(View v)
    {
      if (v.GetType() == typeof(LinearLayout))
      {
        var view = (LinearLayout)v;
        if (view.ChildCount == 0)
        {
          ((Activity)view.Context).RunOnUiThread(() => view.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible);
          return;
        }
        else
        {
          ((Activity)view.Context).RunOnUiThread(() => view.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible);
          for (int i = 0; i < view.ChildCount; i++)
          {
            SetVisibility(view.GetChildAt(i));
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        ((Activity)v.Context).RunOnUiThread(() => v.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible);
        return;
      }
      
    }
```

So in general, what would cause a View to not display on screen even though the visibility of the View and it's parent are both set to `Visible`?

**Update:** The purpose of `myLayout` in the above code is to hold a variable number of TextViews that will be shown (`Visible`) or hidden (`Invisible`) as needed. When new TextViews need to be shown, the previous ones are removed with `View.RemoveAllViews`.

**Update #2:** I tried replacing `myLayout` which was a LinearLayout to just a TextView and instead of inflating the view as needed, I just set the value of the `TextView`. I get similar behavior where even though there should be multiple lines of data, the TextView will *sometimes* only shows the first line. In this case, the surrounding ScrollView is only drawn on screen to fit the first line. I believe the root of the problem is getting the screen to redraw or display views when they are added or changed during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. I tested your code in a new blank xamarin.android project and the textview will show.

The activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:id="@+id/myScollLayout"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The my_view.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code add the text to the textview:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            var myLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myScollLayout);

            View myView = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_view, null);
            TextView text1 = myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);
            TextView text2 = myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text2);
            TextView text3 = myView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text3);
            text1.Text = "text 1";
            text2.Text = "text 2";
            text3.Text = "text 3";
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            myLayout.AddView(myView, p);
            myView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
```

The result image:

[image]

In addition, I also tried to put the code about add text to the textview into a button's click event. I got the same result.

Comment: if you were to add a button that called `removeAllViews` from `myLayout`, and then pressed the button to add the text views back in, would you get the same result? alternatively, if you had a button that toggled the visibility of `myLayout`, would the text continue to appear when you add it back in?

Comment: Actually, I can't understand what you want clearly. But I tested again with a button change myLayout's Visibility. If **myLayout's Visibility is ViewStates.Visible, the text view will show in the myLayout**. So you said the text view didn't show. Did you set the `myLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;`? @brutal11

Comment: In addition, could you please show the code about the button you said? I didn't know the details about your code so I can't reproduce your problem. I added the **removeAllViews** button and when I pressed it, the button and the text view will be deleted. And then I pressed the add textview button, the textview will show in the mylayout without the **removeAllViews** button. @brutal11

Comment: Yes I am setting `myLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;`. One of the challenges may be that my code is not triggering these UI events via buttons, but rather when the application receives data, it updates the screen by adding the TextViews to `myLayout`. I'll have to do some more work to see if triggering these with buttons has any impact.

In general, it may be more a question of (based on what I'm seeing): why would a view appear as `Invisible` when the view and its parent(s) are all set to `Visible`?

Comment: I can't reproduce a view appear as Invisible when the view and its parent(s) are all set to Visible, in my project it's always visible. And for the xamarin .android project, if you didn't use the multiple threads, all the code will run on the main thread(UI thread). But you can try to put it in the button's event to test. @brutal11

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was not able to achieve what I wanted with dynamically added views as shown in the original post. The only way I could get this to work reliably was to have a set number of inflated layouts and inflate them all in `OnCreate`, then set their visibility as needed. Perhaps this may be a clue for anyone who might know what could cause the original issue.